# How compatible are rack-mount server rails across different manufacturers?

Tags: rack, rackmount

I have a bunch of rackmount chassis manufactured by Chenbro which were sold without rack-mount rails.

I have an opportunity to purchase a bunch of second-hand rack-mount rails manufactured by Gigabyte. I couldn't find online any schematics with the exact position of the holes (there are photos, but they are not precise enough).

1. What should I look at to know if they are compatible?
2. In general, do most rack-mount rails use some sort of standards in terms of the position of the holes in order to be compatible with most chassis, or each company prefers to have their own standards which would be incompatible with most chassis of other companies?
3. The rails seem to be for 1U servers. My chassis are 4U (but not particularly heavy, since they are mostly empty inside). Does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, they aren't standardized, even within the same brand of chassis. Save yourself a lot of pain and research the exact rails you need and buy those exact ones. I'm a big fan of tool-less rails, but they do tend to be more expensive.

You might get lucky, but it's a gamble.